# Storing a byte array in SQL with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Is there a way with Powershell to store a byte array in SQL Server, then retrieve the byte array from SQL Server again, and use it as a byte array?

Answer (score -1):

Convert to string:
byte[] myByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("a string"); 
string myString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myByteArray );

Store the string in in SQL, retrieve and convert back to byteArray (I'll leave those steps for you)